# Is there a Preproccessor 'AND' Directive

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is there a Preproccessor `AND` directive? If not how would you suggest I tackle the following task?

```
#define INSTALL_V8
#define INSTALL_V9
#define INSTALL_V10  // Using preprocessor directives and not static variables to
// avoid packaging unnecessary code into the application/installer

#ifdef INSTALL_V8 AND INSTALL_V9 AND INSTALL_V10
  #define CHECK_BOX_STRT_Y 60 // move the start y up so we have room to fit 3 checkboxes in the window
#else
  #define CHECK_BOX_STRT_Y 80 // place 1st checkbox in middle of window
#endif
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `defined` like this:

```
#if defined(INSTALL_V8) && defined(INSTALL_V9) && defined(INSTALL_V10)
```

Answer (score 4):

nest the conditions

```
#ifdef CONDITION1
# ifdef CONDITION2
# endif
#endif
```